# How to Swap Value in Eiffel Programming Language?

Tags: eiffel

I am defining like this in eiffel to swap the value. We cannot use the way we define in c++.

```
 swap(x,y):INTEGER
         do
            x;y := y;x
       end
```

How to define functions in Eiffel? 
I want to define heap sort but it is showing some error can someone help me clear my doubt about function.

```
 heapsort(array,N):INTEGER  -- heap_sort
            do
                heap_size : INTEGER
                heap_size := N

                build(array,N)

                from i := N until i >=2 loop

                    swap(array(1), array(i))
                    heap_size := heap_size-1
                    heapify(array,1,heap_size-1)

                end
            end
```

Answer (score 1):

All variables in Eiffel are passed by value, so there is no way to pass two variables or expressions and swap their values. As a result, the `swap` should look like

```
swap (i, j: INTEGER; data: ARRAY [...]) -- Here and below `...` stands for the type of elements.
        -- Swap items of `data` at indexes `i` and `j`.
    require
        valid_i: data.valid_index (i)
        valid_j: data.valid_index (j)
    local
        value: ...
    do
        value := data [i]
        data [i] := data [j]
        data [j] := value
    ensure
        new_at_i: data [i] = old data [j]
        new_at_j: data [j] = old data [i]
    end
```

Then, the call to this procedure in your example would look like

```
swap (1, i, array)
```

*Side notes.*

1. It's unclear why the feature `heap_sort` returns an integer. Also, it should specify types of arguments like

   ```
   heap_sort (array: ARRAY [...]; N: INTEGER)
   ```
2. Do you really need `N`? It's possible to retrieve lower and upper bounds of the array with `array.lower` and `array.upper`.
3. Code and declarations in Eiffel are split, so you would write

   ```
   local
       heap_side: INTEGER
   do
       heap_size := N
   ```
4. The expression after `until` specifies the condition when loop should terminate. With the current condition `i >= 2` the loop would never execute because `i >= 2` is true right from the beginning.